diagnosing chronyc sources unusable - time won't sync
Trying to get chrony working on a LAN, in RHEL-8.10.  The service on either my chrony server or a client appears to be functional as reported by a service chronyd status -l.  However I cannot get time to sync between the two, they are off by a couple minutes.
# this command is performed on a time client server, having ip 192.168.1.4 for example

chronyc> sources -a -v

  .-- Source mode  '^' = server, '=' = peer, '#' = local clock.
 / .- Source state '*' = current best, '+' = combined, '-' = not combined,
| /             'x' = may be in error, '~' = too variable, '?' = unusable.
||                                                 .- xxxx [ yyyy ] +/- zzzz
||      Reachability register (octal) -.           |  xxxx = adjusted offset,
||      Log2(Polling interval) --.      |          |  yyyy = measured offset,
||                                \     |          |  zzzz = estimated error.
||                                 |    |           \
MS Name/IP address         Stratum Poll Reach LastRx Last sample
===============================================================================
^? 192.168.1.1                   3   6   377     5  -1500us[-1705us] +/-  500ms

# I edited the name/ip here for posting, it resolves to the hostname via dns in our little LAN

And chronyc tracking reports all zeros, versus on another server that is online [intranet] is sync's to a dedicated time server and here the time matches that from time.gov to the second, and chronyc tracking reports with things like System time     : 0.000830548 seconds fast of NTP time and not all zeros.
on my LAN systems, I have tried setenforce 0 and service firewalld stop and neither helped.
What causes the '?' = unusable in chronyc sources ?  This seems to be the most obvious problem comparing between a working setup versus non-working.
I feel like my error is on my RHEL-8.10 server that I am trying to make a chrony time server that others sync to, is there anything special in that /etc/chrony.conf that is needed that isn't obviously already documented in that default file as provided by redhat?  Below is my /etc/chrony.conf from the server I want to be the time server on my LAN having ip 192.168.1.1, which does not time sync to anything else.  Am I missing anything below that would cause the '?' = unusable to happen when doing chronyc sources -a -v from a time client on my LAN?
# Record the rate at which the system clock gains/losses time.
driftfile /var/lib/chrony/drift

# Allow the system clock to be stepped in the first three updates
# if its offset is larger than 1 second.
makestep 1.0 3

# Enable kernel synchronization of the real-time clock (RTC).
rtcsync

# Enable hardware timestamping on all interfaces that support it.
#hwtimestamp *

# Increase the minimum number of selectable sources required to adjust
# the system clock.
#minsources 2

# Allow NTP client access from local network.
allow 192.168.1.0/24

# Serve time even if not synchronized to a time source.
local stratum 10

# Specify file containing keys for NTP authentication.
keyfile /etc/chrony.keys

# Get TAI-UTC offset and leap seconds from the system tz database.
leapsectz right/UTC

# Specify directory for log files.
logdir /var/log/chrony

# Select which information is logged.
#log measurements statistics tracking

And on my clients their chrony.conf simply has server 192.168.1.1 iburst at the top.

You don't let your server connect to an upstream NTP server?

there is no upstream,  just 11 systems on a LAN.  I want to make one of them the time server so they all have the same time.  It is an isolated LAN without any kind of external [internet] access.

in my case the cause for the ? = unusable as reported by chronyc sources -a -v was not actually having port 123 UDP open in the firewall on my time server.
My /etc/firewalld/zones/custom.xml file did have a line in it to open 123/udp, however doing a firewall-cmd --list-all did not display that port number.  The solution in my case was to:

re-edit the firewall xml file, do a firewall-cmd --complete-reload and make sure 123/udp was displayed when doing a firewall-cmd --list-all.

of course you could also do a systemctl stop firewalld


however even turning off the firewall on both the server and client, I observed the chronyd service needed to be restarted on the client, and then you should wait at least 30 seconds before doing a chronyc sources -a -v to see if you get a ^* response instead of ^?.  When I first did everything typing fast, I was always getting ^? from chronyc sources causing frustration.
I found the chrony.service also had to be restarted on the client, only then did chrony sources -a -v about 30 seconds later report with a * = best instead of unusable.  And chronyc tracking then did not have all zeros.

